# HTML reset after form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

today I started learning JavaScript and I want to calculate two numbers from a text field, using JavaScript. I want to display the result as HTML on the website itself. When I use a form to submit the values, it keeps resetting my modified HTML (the result section shows the actual result for a second but keeps switching back to the default value).

This does not happen when using a button. But since I want to add radio buttons to choose from a mathematical operation, I'd prefer a form (I'm also not quite sure how to determine which radio button is checked via JS).

this is my HTML-Form

```
   <form name="calcForm" onsubmit="calc(num1.value, num2.value)">
  <input type="text" id="num1">
  <input type="text" id="num2">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This is my resolution-section (which resets when using a form)

```
<div id="calcRes" style="display:block;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

The actual JavaScript function

```
  function calc(num1, num2) {
  var res = Number(num1)+Number(num2);
  document.getElementById('calcRes').innerHTML = "Result is " + res;
}
```

As I said above, the result is being displayed when using a button instead of a 'form'

```
<button onclick="calc(num1.value, num2.value)">Calculate</button>
```

I'd like to know why the modified HTML switches back to default, a solution how to avoid this and if there's any "bad practice" in my code. I've also tried to search for this issue but I can't find anything. I guess, this is just a noobish problem but as I said, I'm a complete beginner so please be patient with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is being submitted and hence the page is being  reloaded. To avoid this you need to prevent the form' submission. In your case

```
<form name="calcForm" onsubmit="calc(num1.value, num2.value); return false;">
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Just beat me to it; I was also going to mention `num1`/`num2` *should* be defined for better browser compatibility.

Comment: Thank you so much! Because I was working with a local file, I did not notice the reload. :)

Answer (score 0):

`<form> onsubmit` default functionality is to submit the form information to the server and resets the page on click of the `submit` button.

In the above code, on click of the `form` submit, the function `calc` is called, but it also resets the page after the function is called, which is why the modified HTML switches back to default.

This default behaviour can be prevented by using `event.preventDefault()` which cancels the event if it is cancelable. Adding this line to the start your `calc` function would prevent the default behaviour.

[Refer to MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) for more information about `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score -1):

You could simply squeeze in the line

```
document.getElementById("calcForm").reset();
```

after the line

```
document.getElementById('calcRes').innerHTML = "Result is " + res;
```

But you have to add the `id="calcForm"` to your `<form>` Tag.

The submit-Action is to understand as simply ending all the user input and do something with it. And after that, you don't need you inputs anymore so it will be deleted automatically. With the button-click, the form does not know that you are actually done with your input. its just a button-click. so it will leave the input as it is.

Comment: This doesn't work, and also will not answer what user is trying to ask